# How can i make a countdown timer in C# that accounts for hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: c#

I am not a good programmer, it's rather my hobby.
So please don't judge me for being bad at programming. This is my current code ive made for the countdown timer.

```
int i = 000000;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   {
            i++;
            textBox1.Text = i.ToString() + "00:00:00";
   }
}
```

When I run the timer. then the TextBox1 isn't showing 00:00:01, but it's showing 100;00;00.
Thank you for reading my post and again, sorry for having soo bad programming knowledge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
textBox1.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you know how to use `Timer` but your problem is with `string`, when you use `+` on `string` you are `concatenating` them, so say `"hello" + " world"` is equal to `"hello world"`, so when you concat `i` with `00:00:00` the output you see is very logical.
you can use snippet below to achieve your goal(just replace your form class content with this)

```
private Timer _timer;
private Label _label;
private int _elapsedSeconds;
public Form1()
{
    _timer = new Timer
    {
        Interval = 1000,
        Enabled = true
    };
    _timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
    {
        _elapsedSeconds++;
        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_elapsedSeconds);
        _label.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    };

    _label = new Label();

    Controls.Add(_label);
}
```

### Edit

Tnx to @Juliet Wilson I edited how time is converted to string

Comment: Though you start off with a nice description of the immediate problem, your code solution is kinda convuluted.  Why not use `ToString()` as per **Juliet's** answer instead of the fidly hour/min/sec calculation?

Comment: @shash678, tnx for the link, but my naming convention is taken from Jetbrain reharper

Comment: downvote removed.  thanks for improving your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Stopwatch for that. It will do the magic you need. Here you can find good example of using Stopwatch class in C# https://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch.

Comment: Please mark it as answer as it resolved your problem.

Comment: Well no, not only wouldn't address the immediate problem (formatting), `StopWatch` doesn't have any _count-down_ ability at all.

Comment: @MickyD, although user has stated countdown in question, but looking at code he implied something else

Comment: @hessamhedieh That's true. The answer is borderline comment with a link to a foreign site.  Perhaps if author improves answer I'll upvote :)